# Missing Functions and Changes in Azure Storage SDK 7.2.1

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

Recently we have started upgrading our projects from ASP.NET 4.5 to ASP.NET Core and we are targeting the .NET Standard 1.6 framework. Most of the projects have been migrated but we are particularly facing issues with projects which have reference to Azure Storage SDK. Initially we were using SDK version 7.0.0, but since it was not supported in .NET Standard 1.6, we had to upgrade SDk to 7.2.1. But it seems that a lot of functions have been removed from the new version, for e.g. CloudTable.CreateQuery(). And also it seems that all the functions have been made async.

Is it an expected thing, or am I missing something here? Is there are a change or a upgrade document for all the changes that has been done? I could not find any document for all these changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it an expected thing, or am I missing something here?

Yes, this is an expected thing. We could check the CloudTable class in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.aspx). And we could find CreateQuery function in that article. However we could not use CreateQuery function and we only could use async method. I think it is caused by the following, and this is a default behavior：

```html
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

As we know that, we only could use Azure storage async method in portable library and win8. In asp.net core it imports "portable-net45+win8". So I think this is a reason. If you update your application to Asp.net core. I think you need to rewrite the Azure Storage code.